# problem with an app on my phone

Tags: android

i have wrote an app getting rss feed from the website of my university.in the eclipse emulator the app  runs with no problem and i can reed the rss.but as i transferred it to my mobile(samsung gti 9000) the screen freeze when i push the button for the rss news...also,if i go for the menu button of the phone and change dom to sax the phone pops out a message to force down...any idea?may my phone has a problem?please keep on mind that my phone works on greek language and the emulator on english,i dont know if this matter..

Comment: why dont connect your phone to the computer, select it from launch screen on eclipse and watch what logcat says... i mean, can you give us more info with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be that your phone downloads the feed slower than the emulator. Easiest solution is to add some logging to your app and/or run it with debugging, connect your phone to your pc and use the phone instead of the emulator.

Comment: yes i will do it but unfortunately i have lost my data cable so i have to buy one first...i dont now if the phone downloads the feed slower,i was waiting for 3 minutes and the screen was still freezed!..

Comment: sorry but how will i make my device emulator for eclipse??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html i found the answer here!!